# How display two fields sums in the same query in HIve

Tags: hadoop, count, hive

I have a `Hive` table with the following fields:

```
id STRING , x STRING
```

where x can have values such as 'c'.

I need a query that display number of rows where column `x` contains a value 'c' and the number of rows where `x` has values are other than 'c'.

```
id | count(x='c') | count(x<>'c')
---|--------------|--------------
1  | 3            | 7
```

I don't know if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
SELECT sum(if(x='c',1,0)), sum(if(x!='c',1,0)) FROM table_name;
```

This will print two columns. I didn't understand the `id` field in your sample output.

Comment: I think the OP ment to group by ID in which case it will be `SELECT id,sum(if(x='c',1,0)), sum(if(x!='c',1,0)) FROM table_name group by id`;

Comment: but there's gonna be only a single row in the output @dimamah

Comment: Yea but it doesn't make sense to have a column that only hold one constant value.